# Make a UITableView scroll from top to bottom over a set period of time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, animation, scroll

I'm trying to get my `UITableView` to slowly scroll downwards at a steady speed, which I can specify. I've used `scrollToRowAtIndexPath`, but whether or not I choose to animate it, it's an almost instant movement. I'm looking at something that moves much more slowly.

I did wonder whether I could do something with a UIView animation block, moving one `indexPath.row` at a time, but since my cells are different heights, this would cause uneven animation speed.

Any other ways I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it with this..

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.025 target:self selector:@selector(scrollTableView) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

And..

```
- (void) scrollTableView {

    float w = 1;

    CGPoint scrollPoint = self.tableView.contentOffset;
    scrollPoint.y = scrollPoint.y + w;
    if (scrollPoint.y >= self.tableView.contentSize.height - (self.tableView.frame.size.height - 100)  || scrollPoint.x <= -self.tableView.frame.size.height + 924) {
    w *= -1;
    }
    [self.tableView setContentOffset: scrollPoint animated: NO];
}
```

Comment: Make sure you deal with the user interacting with the table while you do this as well as the user leaving the view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can always decrement the contentOffset y axis over time.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go buddy. Just change the animateWithDuration to higher seconds like 1 or 1.5 to see if it achieves the effect you want. Make sure you include QuartzCore library and `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in your *.m file. This is as easy as it gets

```
-(IBAction)modeTableSlowly
{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{

            //here tblSimpleTable2 is tableView
            [tblSimpleTable2 setFrame:CGRectMake(183, 56, 137, 368)];

    } completion:nil];

}
```